# Windows Server 2003 R2 sp2 and Exchange 2003 - missing pop-up menu "Exchange Tasks"

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I need to recover database. That's what i doing step-by-step:
- In Exchange System Manager check the server
- Create new Recovery Storage Group
- Add Database to recover
- Mount store for it Database (Mailbox Store) - all finish successful

Next step - I need check user and in pop-up menu click on "Exchange Tasks...", but in menu i see only "Help". Main question - why I have not "Exchange Tasks" and how I can get it?

But I can see "Exchange Tasks" in "First storage Group"-Mailbox-User.

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks, Denis

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you managed to mount the DB, navigate to "Exchange Org" -> "Servers" -> " Your Exchange Server Name" - > "First Storage Group" -> "Mailboxes", right click on the mailboxes there.

And there is no Windows 2003 R2 :)

Comment: I need do it not in "First Storage Group", but in "Recovery Storage Group". I know about "First Storage Group", and wrote about it in question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this problem by installing Exchange Service Pack 2.